# Typescript Servicestack Client authentication for SSE events

Tags: authentication, typescript, cookies, servicestack, server-sent-events

I am trying to use typescript [servicestack-client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client) to hook to SSE events from ServiceStack Server.

The authentication is made by sending `Authenticate` class and receiving the sesssion cookies:

```
import { ServerEventsClient } from 'servicestack-client';

export class ServicestackService {
    private sseClient: ServerEventsClient;

    constructor() {
        this.createSseClient();
    }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        let request = new Authenticate(username, password);
        return this.sseClient.serviceClient.post(request);
    }

    startClient() {
        this.sseClient.start();
        console.log('eventSource created');
    }

    subscribeChannel(channel: string) {
        this.sseClient.subscribeToChannels(channel);
    }

    private createSseClient() {
        this.sseClient = new ServerEventsClient('http://ss_api_url', ['*'], {
        handlers: { ...define handlers for onConnect & onMessage here... }
        }
    }

}
```

The code above successfully authenticates agains servicestack API and secured API requests works well.
The `startClient()` method is called after all the login authentication was finished and creates the `eventSource` object as a property in `this.sseClient`.

But this object has `withCredentials: false`**!**
Therefore any of the following channel subscription fails as not authenticated because servicestack client is not sending the `Cookies` header.

How can I achieve authenticated SSE connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added support for specifying `withCredentials` EventSource option in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/cf4033eda8263cb3cd8e0ce0775f5a4ed1079daf) which defaults to `true` so it will be automatically enabled if you upgrade to the latest **v0.0.34** of [servicestack-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicestack-client).

If needed, it can be disabled with:

```
var sseClient = new ServerEventsClient('http://ss_api_url', ['*'], { ... });

sseClient.withCredentials = false;
```